# GraphQL query header with variable not setting on first render

Tags: reactjs, react-native, graphql, jwt

I am using graphQL in react native project. I am passing headers `(cookie/authorization)` in context object of query, in `useMutation` or `useQuery`. `[Problem is only on iOS App]`

The basic system of the app is user signup the profile, and verify, on initial signup the property `finishedAccountSetup: false` is false. so when they log in on very first time, then the active navigation stack is setup navigation stack. When they fills up the information its calls `updateuser` mutation. this mutation requires header to pass in query. So once the user reach to last screen to setup and submit the information even though the `jwt` is not undefined the mutation not passing the jwt, seems undefined is passed. the jwt is fetching from the redux store, also tried to pass as navigation parameters, I was guessing if at the very beginning of render useMutation finding the jwt is undefined when it not finished fetching from store. But passing via parameter it should be there in very beginning.  But it does not works there as well.

The second case is, if the account is marked setup from database and try logging in first time, when user successfully logging  in the navigation stack is changed to home navigation stack and the user redirecting to the home page. Where there is useQuery mutation and the `jwt` is passing the same way. But the `jwt` is not passing once logged in. But if I kill the session of app and re open the app, its working fine. It passing `jwt` and query returning results. Once the app is killed and re open the query and `jwt` is working on all screens. But at very first time after logging in and coming to the home screen its not passing `jwt` even though the variable is not undefined.

The problem is only seeing in iOS device not on android. Its working fine on android.

useMutations: variable `jwt` is never undefined during first render, tried checking this with `console.log(jwt)`

```
  const { jwt, pushToken } = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.auth);

  const [updateUser, updateUserData] = useMutation(UPDATE_USER_MUTATION, {
     context: {
       headers: {
         cookie: `jwt=${jwt}`,
         authorization: jwt ? `Bearer ${jwt}` : '',
       },
     },
  });
```

useQuery: Using this query in home page, when user logs in first time from ios device, then the `jwt` is not passing to the header. variable `jwt` is never undefined during first render though, tried checking this with `console.log(jwt)`. But if the user kill the app session and re open the app then the query is working perfectly. But when logging in the navigation state changing and transferring to home stack navigator and on first render even though the jwt is not undefined its not passing as header.

```
  const { jwt, user, pushToken } = useSelector(
    (state: RootState) => state.auth
  );

  const {
    data: my_info,
    error: my_infoError,
    loading: my_infoLoading,
    refetch: my_infoRefetch,
  } = useQuery(GET_ME, {
        context: {
           headers: {
              cookie: `jwt=${jwt}`,
              authorization: jwt ? `Bearer ${jwt}` : '',
            },
        },
  });
```

What could be the possible reason for this? Is there any way to register `useQuery` or `useMutation` one first render after few seconds? I tried `refetch` query after few seconds using `useEffect` that doesn't work though.

I am not sure now, when the query is registered by the react engine that its finding the jwt is undefined? or not setting the `context` object. Is there any way to find out the issue or is there any solution for this?

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used below script and on `app.js` file and got the log of jwt using `console.log()` on server side. and found that, this is setting the jwt twice in ios like `'jwt="jwt_value",jwt="jwt_value"'` while in android its just one `'jwt="jwt_value"'` so I just used the basic `JavaScript` to solve the issue, `.split('jwt=').pop()` to get the last jwt token. And now its working fine.

```
 import fs from 'fs';
 import util from 'util';

 const log_file = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/debug.log', {
   flags: 'w',
 });
 const log_stdout = process.stdout;
 const log_stderr = process.stderr;

 console.log = function (d: any) {
     log_file.write(util.format(d) + '\n');
     log_stdout.write(util.format(d) + '\n');
     log_stderr.write(util.format(d) + '\n');
 };

 const access = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/stdout.log', {
   flags: 'w',
 });
 process.stdout.write = process.stderr.write = access.write.bind(access);

 process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
    console.error(err && err.stack ? err.stack : err);
 });
```

This is the code log the error on server side. Thanks